# javascript regex to allow letters, numbers, periods, hyphens, underscores, and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to affix form data (username) to a url.  On the site, a username can consist of letters, numbers, spaces, hyphens, underscores, and periods.

I'm trying to create a javascript regex that allows those characters, but only those characters.

What I have so far will allow, for example:

User Name

But it will also allow, User Name&

I've searched many stackover flow posts but have not yet solved this. Thank you very much for your suggestions. Here is what I have..

```
<script>
  function process() {
    var regexp1=new RegExp("[^[0-9A-Za-z_.-]+$]");


    var url = "http://www.website.com/page.php?data=" + document.getElementById("url").value;

    if (regexp1.test(document.getElementById("url").value)) {
      alert("Only numbers, letters, hypens, periods, spaces and underscores are allowed");
      return false;
    }
    location.href = url;
    return false;
  }
</script>

<form onSubmit="return process();">
  <br>
  <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="30" name="url" id="url">
  <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your if statement is reversed.  You should check when the regex DOES NOT match instead:

```
!regexp1.test(document.getElementById("url").value)
```

Also I believe the original regex is wrong/inaccurate try the one shown below:

```js
function process() {
    var regexp1=new RegExp("^[0-9A-Za-z_.-]+$");

    var url = "http://www.website.com/page.php?data=" + document.getElementById("url").value;

    if (!regexp1.test(document.getElementById("url").value)) {
        console.log("Only numbers, letters, hypens, periods, spaces and underscores are allowed");
    } else {
        console.log("Passed validation.");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="30" name="url" id="url">
<input type="button" onclick="process()">
```

Comment: Thank you GantTheWanderer.  I tried !regexp1.test instead with the suggested regex expressions from above and here were my results. (/^[\w\s.-]+$/i .. url didn't load) and (/^[ A-Za-z0-9_-.\s]*$/i -- the alert message was triggered even though only letters, numbers, and a space was used)

Comment: I added a working example of the code so you can compare with your own.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same results.   One note, when clicking the "Go" button previously a page would attempt to load.  Here though there is not that attempt.. as if the go button is inactive.  I'll keep playing around with it. Thank you for your follow up.

Comment: yes this just logs the information to the console, you just need to replace the lines that log to console with the things you actually want to do

Comment: just copy my regular expression and reverse the if statement and you should be good to go

Comment: Thank you @GantTheWanderer.  I got it to work and I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem also I highly recommend this free program to get comfortable with regular expressions.  Its a easy tool to test regex against other strings and breaks down the regex into logicals pieces that help you understand inaccuracies and errors.  http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Answer (score 5):

Your regex should be :

```
/^[ A-Za-z0-9_-.\s]*$/i
```

Explanation :

```
^   : Begging of string 
A-Z : Uppercase Characters 
a-z : Lowercase Characters 
0-9 : Numbers 
_-. : Special Characters  you requested
\s  : Spaces 
*   : Allow repeat
$   : End of string 
/i  : Case insensitive
```

You can replace `A-Za-z0-9_` with `\w`
And your If stament should check for the inverse :

```
if(!regexp1.test...
```

And at the end of the function it's better to make it

```
return true;
```

I suggest you check JQuery for more advanced, easier Javascript code
Hope this help

Comment: Thank you MeNotMe.  I tried changing the regex, and then changing the regex and also changing the "if" statement, and the end of the function to "true".  In all cases, the URL didn't load. Nor did I get the alert message when trying with a special character.

Comment: /^[ A-Za-z0-9_\-.\s]*$/i the last - is processed as a to..from

Answer (score 4):

as far as the regex you need to anchor it with `^` and `$` to make it mean "whole thing" and avoid partial mathching, also your space is outside the character class and should be *in*. Additionally, we can get 'letters/numbers/underscore' with `\w+`, even inside a character class. Finally we can make use of the `i` flag to not worry about capitalized letters:

`/^[\w\s.-]+$/i`

https://regex101.com/r/47l22K/1

Comment: Thank you sweaver2112.     
 
I tried changing the regex, and the URL didn't load. Nor did I get the alert message when trying with a special character.